# Core data does not save the data properly

Tags: swift

#### EDITED

I have a UITableView which displays multiple social media posts. I use the Prefetch Source Delegate for prefetching Posts and I use Core Data to be stored after being fetched from web server. Problem that I have is that I get no error, but the data does not stay saved between launches in CoreData.

**Snip of code**

```
 func configureDataSourceTable(){
        
        self.dataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource<String,String>(tableView: self.table_view){
            (tableView, indexPath, ref) -> UITableViewCell? in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CheckInCell
    
                if !self.postData.currentPostFetching(ref: ref){
                    self.postData.fetchPost(ref: ref) { post in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.setPostNeedsUpdate(ref: ref)//reconfigure items
                        }
            return cell
        }
       

    func fetchPost(ref: String,completion : (PostStruct)->Void) {
        
        
        if self.dataContainer.postIsPartOfCoreData(ref: ref){
            var postStruct = self.dataContainer.getPostStructFromDB(ref: ref)
            completion(postStruct)
        }else{ //has to be downloaded from web server
            Task {
                    let post = await getPostFromServer()//not relevant in understanding problem
                    var postStruct = self.convertDataToPost(post)
                    completion(postStruct)
                    self.dataContainer.savePostStruct(post: postStruct)
                }
                
            }    
        }
```

Class of the DataContainer subclass of NsPersistentStore

```
    func savePostStruct(post_struct : PostStruct,image_data : String){


       Task.detached {
       var postObject = PostCore.init(context : self.viewContext)
       postObject.name = "Test"
       var image = ImageCore.init(context: self.viewContext)
       imageObject.data = image_data
       postObject.image = imageObject
        do {
                    if Thread.isMainThread {
                        print("Running on the main thread parent")
                    }else {
                        print("Other thread")
                    }
                    try self.viewContext.save()
                    print("Reference \(post_struct.ref) child saved")
                }catch {
                    print("Error that produced \(post.ref) catched while trying to savethe data on child: \(error.localizedDescription),number : \(error)");
                }
                if post_struct.ref == "AAAA"{
                    
                    var post = PostCore.fetchRequest()
                    var predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "ref like %@", post.ref!)
                    fetchCheckIn.predicate = predicate
                    fetchCheckIn.fetchLimit = 1
                    fetchCheckIn.includesPropertyValues = true
                    let result = try! self.viewContext.fetch(fetchCheckIn)
                    print(result)
//This line returns the Object
                    print(self. checkPostExistHasPictures(refPost: post.ref))
//This is the line where always come (false, false) meaning that the Post is not saved
                }
            }

func getPostStructFromDB(refPost : String)async->PostStruct {
        
        
            return await self.viewContext.perform{
                var fetchPost = PostCore.fetchRequest()
                var predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "ref like %@", refPost)
                fetchPost.predicate = predicate
                fetchPost.fetchLimit = 1
                fetchPost.includesSubentities = true
                fetchPost.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
                fetchPost.includesPropertyValues = true
                
                let result = try? self.viewContext.fetch(fetchCheckIn)
                var refPost = result.first.ref
               
                return PostStruct(ref : ref, image: refPost.image.data)
            }
        }
    }



func checkPostExistHasPictures(refPost : String)->(Bool,Bool){
        
        var fetchCheckIn = CheckInCore.fetchRequest()
        var predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "ref like %@", refPost)
        fetchCheckIn.predicate = predicate
        fetchCheckIn.fetchLimit = 1
        
        
        var exist = false
        var hasPicture = false
        
            self.viewContext.performAndWait {
                
                
                do{
                    let result = try? self.viewContext.fetch(fetchCheckIn)
                    if result?.first == nil {
                    }else {
                        print("Exists with reference \(reference_checkin)")
                        if result!.first!.pic_ref == nil {
                            exist = true
                            hasPicture = false
                        }else if result!.first!.image!.count != 0 {
                            exist = true
                            hasPicture = true
                        }
                    }
                }catch {
                    print("error catched")
                }
            }
        return(exist, hasPicture)
        }
        
    }
```

Relation between PostCore and ImageCore is zero to many.
I don't get any error code or error message. I commented the line where I get the error. I have tried all possible ways using a backGroundContext each time a save is made to not block the main thread and still is the same problem.

Comment: _"some of them are not saved"_, this is very vague and unfortunately the only description of the issue you have provided.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  I wrote as this, because I can't find any rule to describe which   posts are and are not saved.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is extremely confusing.

Why have you got `Task` scattered everywhere, you are doing no `async/await` work?

Your `savePostStruct` method takes a parameter called `post` which contains your data, then you immediately replace it with a value of the same name of type PostCore, which is presumably a managed object, then you only set one value on it.

Then, when you come to fetch an item, there's nothing there, because you haven't written anything to the managed object besides the name "Test".

At the very least, you have to change this line:

```
var post = PostCore.init(context : self.viewContext)
```

To

```
let postObject = PostCore(context: self.viewContext)
```

Then you won't get confused between the managed object and the struct you're passing in.

You are also saving the context before you've written any of the values to it.

Comment: @jrhurton I have changed the lines. Can you please explain why you say that when I fetch an item there is nothing because I haven't written anything. I assign to the PostCore object a name and a relation object. If there is something wrong please tell me.

Comment: It looked like you were using the `ref` quite a lot, and you never assign that.